# Python program to store and update inventory

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Retial_inventory is a list of three dictionaries (stores and details on three products they sell).

*Goal:*
I want my program to take user input on quantity and product then find the store that sells the product at lowest price and update it's quantity accordingly.

*Problem:*
However, when the input quantity is more than quantity at lowest price store, it won't take remaining quantity from next store with lowest price.

Here's my code so far:

```py
retailer_inventory = [{'store': 'a', 
                        'book': {'price': 2, 'quantity': 20}, 
                        'pen': {'price': 1, 'quantity': 100}, 
                        'eraser': {'price': 3, 'quantity': 30}}, 
                      {'store': 'b', 
                        'book': {'price': 3, 'quantity': 30}, 
                        'pen': {'price': 2, 'quantity': 20}, 
                        'eraser': {'price': 1, 'quantity': 100}}, 
                      {'store': 'c', 
                      'book': {'price': 1, 'quantity': 100},
                      'pen': {'price': 3, 'quantity': 30}, 
                      'eraser': {'price': 2, 'quantity': 20}}]

products_types = ["book", "pen", "eraser"]
while True:
    product = input("Enter name of product (book/ eraser/ pen): ").lower()
    if product in products_types:
        try:
            quantity = int(input("Enter quantity: "))
        except:
            print("Has to be a number.")
            break
        price_list = []
        if quantity < 0:
            print("Setting quantity to 0.")
        for i in retailer_inventory:
            if i[product]["quantity"] > 0:
                price_list.append((i[product]))
                i[product].update({"store": i["store"]})
        #print(price_list)

        flag = True
        for x in price_list:
            if flag:
                low = x["price"]
                retailer = x["store"]
                flag = False
            if x["price"] < low and x["quantity"] > 0:
                low = x["price"]
                retailer = x["store"]
            if quantity == 0:
                break
            if quantity < x["quantity"]:
                for y in retailer_inventory:
                    if retailer == y["store"]:
                        y[product]["quantity"] = y[product]["quantity"] - quantity
            else: 
                for y in retailer_inventory:
                    if retailer == y["store"]:
                        quantity = quantity - y[product]["quantity"]
                        y[product]["quantity"] = 0
```

Comment: List all item for the given product. Sort by increasing price. Compute the cumulative sum. Identify the first row above the quantity to pick. Update selected stores quantities accordingly. Job is done. Looks like you can benefit of using a database to deal with this kind of problem.

Comment: You have two stores labelled as `b` which seems to be a typo. Why supply also have store reference within their definition? Your datamodel could be changed in order to simplify this task, can it be modified?

Answer (score 0):

First let's reorganize your data model as follow (that would perfectly fit in a database table):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'item': 'book', 'price': 2, 'quantity': 20, 'store': 'a'}, 
    {'item': 'pen', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 100, 'store': 'a'}, 
    {'item': 'eraser', 'price': 3, 'quantity': 30, 'store': 'a'},
    {'item': 'book', 'price': 3, 'quantity': 30, 'store': 'b'}, 
    {'item': 'pen', 'price': 2, 'quantity': 20, 'store': 'b'}, 
    {'item': 'eraser', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 100, 'store': 'b'}, 
    {'item': 'book', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 100, 'store': 'c'},
    {'item': 'pen', 'price': 3, 'quantity': 30, 'store': 'c'}, 
    {'item': 'eraser', 'price': 2, 'quantity': 20, 'store': 'c'}
]

# Load data into frame:
frame = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

Then the operation you want to perform can be written as:

```
def operate(frame, item, quantity):
    """
    Return optimal order in term of price and update stock accordingly
    """
    # Filter item and sort by price:
    data = frame[frame["item"] == item].sort_values("price", ascending=True)
    # Compute cumulative quantity:
    data["cumsum"] = data["quantity"].cumsum()
    # Select store stocks to exhaust:
    taken = data[data["cumsum"] < quantity]
    # Select remaining stores:
    left = data.loc[data.index.difference(taken.index),:]
    # Quantity available on stock to exhaust
    amount = taken["quantity"].sum()
    # Exhaust stocks:
    taken["quantity"] = 0
    # Quantity to get from the remaining store:
    left.loc[left.index[0], "quantity"] -= quantity - amount
    # Assemble new stock state:
    order = pd.concat([taken, left])
    # Compute order quantity as well:
    order["order"] = data["quantity"] - order["quantity"]
    order["subtotal"] = order["order"]*order["price"]
    order = order[order["order"]>0]
    # Update data source:
    frame.loc[order.index, "quantity"] = order["quantity"]
    return order
```

Example of operations:

```
order = operate(frame, "pen", 5)
```

Order 5 pens in store a (best price) and update the stock:

```
  item  price  quantity store  cumsum  order  subtotal
1  pen      1        95     a     100      5         5

     item  price  quantity store
0    book      2        20     a
1     pen      1        95     a
2  eraser      3        30     a
3    book      3        30     b
4     pen      2        20     b
5  eraser      1       100     b
6    book      1       100     c
7     pen      3        30     c
8  eraser      2        20     c
```

And next order will need multiple store to complete:

```
order = operate(frame, "pen", 120)
```

Then it orders 120 pens drawn from 3 stores and update stocks as well:

```
  item  price  quantity store  cumsum  order  subtotal
1  pen      1         0     a      95     95        95
4  pen      2         0     b     115     20        40
7  pen      3        25     c     145      5        15

     item  price  quantity store
0    book      2        20     a
1     pen      1         0     a
2  eraser      3        30     a
3    book      3        30     b
4     pen      2         0     b
5  eraser      1       100     b
6    book      1       100     c
7     pen      3        25     c
8  eraser      2        20     c
```